# Is there possibility to hook up static page to my webapp made in Django?

Tags: html, django

I have my webapp which is simple shop app and i want add to this app page that contain informations like short description about shop, contact to shop and address. And i want for that page to be static page. I dont think that i need to contain this informations in database. I Can make this page in html/css but i dont know how hook up this page to my app. my app main address is http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop and i want for this page to have adress http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop/About_firm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved, I used "flatpages app"
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/